# stuck on creating 'moor_database.g.dart'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-moor

I wanted to generate file **'moor_database.g.dart'** by typing the command **'flutter packages pub run build_runner watch'** but after doing some procedures it just tells: **[INFO] Succeeded after 9.0s with 0 outputs (4 actions)**

And inside the terminal results I saw this warning:
**[WARNING] moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/data/moor.dart: Missing "part 'moor.g.dart';".**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this message because I had my own *file* called **moor.dart** which conflicted with the **moor** library file (that's why that command was not working properly) but Android Studio didn't give any direct errors or warning on that, after **renaming my file name**, everything worked